# Deleting a reference to a variable without affecting the original

Tags: c++, vector, struct, reference

I have a struct which contains a reference to a vector.

I then create a vector of this struct.

I create three three instances of this struct in this vector.

I then erase the second instance of the struct in the vector.

This apparently causes the contents of testData2 to become the same as the contents of testData3!?

How do I stop this from happening?  Is there something I should put in the destructor of the struct to stop this from happening?

Or is what I am doing here terribly bad and if so, why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

struct TESTSTRUCT
{
    int &testInt;
    std::vector<int> &testVector;

    TESTSTRUCT(int &testIntInput, std::vector<int> &testVectorInput)
        :testInt(testIntInput), testVector(testVectorInput) {}

    TESTSTRUCT(const TESTSTRUCT &source)
        :testInt(source.testInt), testVector(source.testVector) {}

    TESTSTRUCT &operator=(const TESTSTRUCT &source)
    {
        testInt = source.testInt;
        testVector = source.testVector;

        return *this;
    }
    virtual ~TESTSTRUCT(){}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> testData1;
    std::vector<int> testData2;
    std::vector<int> testData3;
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;

    testData1.push_back(10);
    testData1.push_back(20);
    testData1.push_back(30);

    testData2.push_back(40);
    testData2.push_back(50);
    testData2.push_back(60);

    testData3.push_back(70);
    testData3.push_back(80);
    testData3.push_back(90);

    std::vector<TESTSTRUCT> *structVector = new std::vector<TESTSTRUCT>();
    structVector->push_back(TESTSTRUCT(a, testData1));
    structVector->push_back(TESTSTRUCT(b, testData2));
    structVector->push_back(TESTSTRUCT(c, testData3));

    std::cout<<&testData1[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<&testData2[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<&testData3[0]<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<testData1[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<testData2[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<testData3[0]<<std::endl;
    structVector->erase(structVector->begin()+1);
    std::cout<<testData1[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<testData2[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<testData3[0]<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<&testData1[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<&testData2[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<&testData3[0]<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00711220
00711258
00717C68
10
40
70
10
70
70
00711220
00711258
00717C68
Press any key to continue . . .
```

EDIT:

This here is an example from a larger program. The instances of the struct are for things I want a renderer to draw, and those things can change their position (and hence where the renderer should draw them).

Comment: A reference is a reference. You seem to have some serious misconceptions, of what all of this code does, and how `std::vector` should be used.

Comment: Your assignment operator has curious semantics - you are assigning the things referenced. That's why your test data vectors are getting modified. What do you actually want to happen to those references on assignment?

Comment: I suspect I should probably be needing pointers instead then?  I want to be able to modify the original data (hence the reference), but I also want to be able to remove the struct instances.  This here is an example from a larger program.  The instances of the struct are for things I want a renderer to draw, and those things can change their position (and hence where the renderer should draw them).

Comment: @Interminable Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620533/thread-safe-vector/23620696#23620696

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not immediately visible. Have a look at the equality operator of `TESTSTRUCT` :

```
TESTSTRUCT &operator=(const TESTSTRUCT &source)
{
    testInt = source.testInt;
    testVector = source.testVector;

    return *this;
}
```

The `testVector` in `this` will obtain a copy of `source.testVector`.

Now, the `structVector` in `main` contains three instances of `TESTSTRUCT`, each bound to its own `std::vector<int>` via a reference. When you call `structVector->erase(structVector->begin()+1);`, `TESTSTRUCT(b, testData2)` is removed from the `structVector`.

The specification of `erase` says that all the vector's elements after the requested erasing position are shifted down (in terms of position) in order for the vector to be memory-contiguous. I don't know if the standard specifies anything about how `erase` needs to be implemented when it comes to copying, but in my implementation (g++), `operator=` is called. This means that the vector stored via reference inside the `TESTSTRUCT` instance referenced by the iterator `structVector->begin()+1` (so, effectively, `structVector[1]`) gets the contents of `structVector[2]`. And because it's a reference, it's essentially the same thing as `testData2` from `main`, which explains why its content is exactly the same as `testData3`.

This is valid, however, as you can see yourself, avoiding such code makes sense when debugging.

Comment: I think I understand.  So from the looks of things I'd probably want to be using pointers for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are over using references (somewhat incorrectly). Your `TESTSTRUCT` objects contains references to `testdata1`, `testdata2` and `testdata3`. So when you modify `structVector`, previous two vectors also get modified. So when you erase second element from `structVector`, the third element takes it's position. So the internal elements, i.e. the `testdata2` is also replaced with `testdata3`in main, as their references are contained in the `struct`.