# C++ storing local variable into a vector prevents it from being destroyed when out of scope

Tags: c++, vector, scope

I've encountered this piece of existing code, and being still new to C++, I don't understand why storing a local variable into a vector makes it still accessible later.

Here's the simplified flow of the code, where BackendCall is some class defined earlier:

```
void SaveBackendCall(BackendCall* backend_call,
                     vector<BackendCall>* logged_calls) {
  logged_calls->push_back(*backend_call);
}

void AddNewCall(vector<BackendCall>* logged_calls) {
  BackendCall backend_call;  // The local variable in question.
  SaveBackendCall(&backend_call, logged_calls);
}

vector<BackendCall> logged_calls;

AddNewCall(&logged_calls);

for (auto i = logged_calls->begin(); i != logged_calls->end(); ++i) {
  i->access_stuff();  // This still works?
}
```

Wouldn't the local variable backend_call in AddNewCall() be destroyed after the function returns?  Then I don't understand what is actually stored in logged_calls.

Would it make sense to convert the vector of BackendCall objects into a vector of unique_ptrs?

Comment: An `std::vector` stores its own copies of everything.

Comment: You have serious misconceptions! Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620533/thread-safe-vector/23620696#23620696

Comment: You need to use `std::move` to `push_back` a `unique_ptr` in a `vector`, for the same reason @juanchopanza has already mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector is a vector of BackendCall objects. When adding objects to a vector, the copy constructor is called.

If you look at SaveBackendCall(), you will notice that it is dereferencing the pointer, which means it is passing in a reference to the object, not the pointer. (If the vector stored pointers, this would be dangerous code since what it is pointing to is going away when the stack goes out of scope.)

So what is happening here is:

1. AddNewCall() creates a local variable.
2. It's passing a pointer to that variable to SaveBackendCall().
3. SaveBackendCall() is passing a reference to the object to push_back().
4. push_back() implicitly makes a copy of the BackendCall and adds it to the vector.

Depending on the complexity and size of the BackendCall object, that copy may be an expensive operation. This can become especially problematic when the push_back requires the vector to be resized.

Yes, IMO it would probably be beneficial to use a vector of smart pointers to avoid unnecessary copies.

Comment: Actually, dereferencing does not produce a reference (despite the name), unless you've overloaded unary `*` to do so.

Comment: Oh, and vector resizes are cheap nowadays when your type is move-aware.

Comment: Thanks for the clear step-by-step explanation. I guess my misunderstanding was that I didn't realize push_back() made an implicit copy of the object.

Answer (score 4):

As the commenters have noted, `vector<T>::push_back(someT)` pushes a *copy* of `someT` onto the vector. It's true that by the time you get to your iteration loop, the original variable named `backend_call` has already departed for the great stack in the sky (which shall never overflow); or possibly it's been reincarnated as `i` (who knows? I don't want to debate religion here). But its memory lives on in the form of a facsimile inside `logged_calls`'s buffer.